# Can you activate separate events on tab change?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, jquery-events, kendo-tabstrip

I am aware that it is possible to set up an event that fires whenever the tab is changed within a tab strip within Kendo UI. However, I'm wondering if it is possible to fire separate events on separate tabs?

For example, I have a tab strip with 6 tabs. I want to fire a different event on entering tab 2 than when entering tab 4 or 5 or 6. I want a separate event for each tab. How can I tell Kendo UI to listen in for which tab we are on to fire these distinct events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please show what you have tried, So it will help us to find the exact problem/solution.

**Anyways,** You can use `active` Event handler in `TabStrip`.

Set an `id` for the tab, And check the `id` and call the `function`, when user activate it.

For more info [Documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip/events/activate)

**This is very simple example**

```
<div id="tabStrip">
    <ul>
        <li id='tab1'>Tab 1</li>
        <li id='tab2'>Tab 2</li>
    </ul>
    <div>Content 1</div>
    <div>Content 2</div>
</div>

<script>
    // event handler for activate
    var onActivate = function(e) {
        // access the activated item via e.item (Element)

        if(e.item.id == "tab1"){

           alert("func 1");

        } else if (e.item.id == 'tab2') {

            alert("func 2");

        }
    };

    // attach activate event handler during initialization
    var tabStrip = $("#tabStrip").kendoTabStrip({
        activate: onActivate
    }).data("kendoTabStrip");
</script>
```